# How to combine to get single row in HashMap?

Tags: android, hashmap

I want to combine multi order item rows to get single row. Like this `{440059=1, Champagne,, 440055=5, Noodle,, 440057=2, Salad Soup,}` When I Log, it show more than 1 row.

```
List<Cart> carts = db.getAllCarts();
for (Cart cart : carts) {
   Map<String, String> order = new HashMap<>();
   order.put(cart.getItemCode(), cart.getQty() + "," + cart.getDescription() + ",");

   Log.d("ord", String.valueOf(order));                    
}
```

Log

```
{440059=1,Champagne,}
{440055=5,Noodle,}
{440057=2,Salad Soup,}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Replace your for each loop with following one

```
for(int i=0;i<carts.size();i++){
          java.util.Map<String, String> order = new java.util.HashMap<>();
          String desc = carts.get(i).getDescription();
          if(i != carts.size()-1)
              {
                desc = desc + ",";  
              }
          order.put(carts.get(i).getItemCode(), carts.get(i).getQty() + "," + desc);
        }
```

Comment: cart is come from where?

Comment: Please check modified answer

Comment: `D/result: {440001=2,BEER,}
D/result: {430001=3,CUVES SPECIAL}` two rows. can i get single row?

Comment: Declare   Map<String, String> order = new HashMap<>(); 
before loop starts and 
put your line  Log.d("ord", String.valueOf(order));   out side the loop

Comment: Whay o/p you want exactly give example

Answer (score 0):

You can use TextUtils.join instead:

```
List<Cart> carts = db.getAllCarts();
String result;
for (Cart cart : carts) {
  Map<String, String> order = new HashMap<>();
  result = TextUtils.join(", ", carts );
}
Log.d("ord", result);
```